# Android Google Map classNotFound exception

Tags: android, exception, classnotfoundexception

Basically I am trying to make an app which displays a Google Map.Here is my code.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="my key goes here"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity class...

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
   }


}
```

When I run it,I get the following message

```
06-22 15:54:03.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 15:54:03.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26187): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to    instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.maptutorial/com.example.maptutorial.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.maptutorial.MainActivity
```

Perhaps I might be doing something wrong in my Manifest File,and can not see it..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maptutorial"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptutorial.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you import google play services to your workspace and added as a lib in your project?

Comment: yes I did my friend. I now don't get any error..But I see grids instead of the Map when I run the app..

Comment: did you enable the toggle on developer console while creating project?

Comment: maybe I am using the wrong key...

Comment: i think you haven't create  project on developer console ,right?

Comment: I did..I created a project which is called MapTutorial..And then used the Services and API Access..In API Access I put the SHA1 key under the "Create New Android Key",and the password was generated..

Comment: But I am not sure if I did something wrong under the Services option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using MAP API version 1 which is deprecated.
Why Cant you use API 2 either Fragment or support-fragment (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC8qEhdHVd3ZtxCR0549UqwnM72h0jgoMY" />
```

Comment: By adding just a MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment,the app will crash for phones using Android version 2.3. You have to us SupportMapFragment. For mobiles that use Android version more than 4.0,there is no need to use SupportMapFragment. I know things could be very messy with maps..

Comment: Its upto developer which one to choose for which version they were developing.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add uses-library in your manifest file,in this case

```
<application>
   ...
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
   android:required="true" />
   ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I had to use the use the SupportMapFragment like this to make it work for android 2.3 .Also had to create a new API key..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And an sample of my java code is this.

```
 public class EmergencyMap extends FragmentActivity {
 static final LatLng ASTYNOMIA = new LatLng(39.620530, 22.401728);
 static final LatLng PYROSVESTIKH = new LatLng(39.632652, 22.398704);                            
 static final LatLng genikonosokomeio = new LatLng(39.642081, 22.422350);
 static final LatLng panosokomeio = new LatLng(39.609993, 22.385722);

private GoogleMap map;
final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_map);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ASTYNOMIA).title("ΑΣΤΥΝΟΜΙΑ"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ASTYNOMIA,15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20),2000,null);


    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PYROSVESTIKH).title("ΠΥΡΟΣΒΕΣΤΙΚΗ"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PYROSVESTIKH,15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20),2000,null);

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(genikonosokomeio).title("ΓΕΝΙΚΟ 
    ΝΟΣΟΚΟΜΕΙΟ"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(genikonosokomeio,15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20),2000,null);

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(panosokomeio).title("ΠΑΝΕΠΙΣΤΗΜΙΑΚΟ 

    ΝΟΣΟΚΟΜΕΙΟ"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(panosokomeio,15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20),2000,null);

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = 
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Το κινητό σας υποστηρίζει GooglePlayServices", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
    }else{
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,RQS_GooglePlayServices); 
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is Google Map API 2. Here is a part of my manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <permission
    android:name="com.example.larissaguide.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="larissa.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="larissa.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_KEY_GOES_HERE" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```